For loop inside slurm script to use a different input for the job to be executed serially
I need to run some 15 instances of an executable at the same location such that it uses the same input files, except one. This one input I need to update with a for loop. Something along the lines of:
#SBATCH -N 1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=256
#SBATCH -p amd
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/share/lib64/psm2-compat/

declare -a value_of_parameter=("a" "b" "c")
for i in "${value_of_parameter}"
do
        str="some_random_string $i"
        sed -i "41s/.*/$str/" inputfile
        mpirun -np 128 /path/to/executable | tee -a out
done
exit

I need to modify only one parameter in inputfile but executable uses other files that stay unchanged during the loop, hence the serial execution requirement.
I cannot get slurm to stop exiting after the job finished with the first instance of value_of_parameter="a" .
Is job array mandatory? I can extract my required output from the appended out file. Switching to wait in place of exit at the end didn't help either. Any help would be appreciated!

"${value_of_parameter}" expands to the first element of the array.  To get all of the elements you need "${value_of_parameter[@]}".

See Using the array name without an index gets the first array element in Bash, ok?.

Shellcheck finds the problem in the code (bad array expansion).  The report that it produces includes a link to more information about the problem and how to fix it.  It's a good idea to run Shellcheck on all new and modified shell code.
